# Clicking unactive window using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have multiple applications running where I'm trying to automate some clicking. I've gotten the (x,y) coordinate of the item I'd like to click on an inactive window.

I have defined the following function:

```
def clickLocation(windowName,x,y):
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None,windowName)
    app = Application()
    app.connect(handle = hwnd)
    app.window(title=windowName).click(button = 'left', coords = (int(x),int(y)))
```

When I call this function with the correct window name the inactive window is clicked, but not at the location (x,y). Rather it clicks where the current cursor location is. Is there a way to click the inactive window at the specified location without moving the cursor and keeping the window inactive?

Comment: What do you mean by `inactive` window? is it minimized or not in the foreground or not in focus?

Comment: Not in the foreground or focus.

Comment: use `set_focus()` on window before performing any action.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  but that isn't an option. I need to keep the window out of focus while performing this operation.

Comment: Wierd, may be some more explanation will help.